# How to constrain the Gaussian process model output ranging between 0 and 1?

Tags: gaussian-process

It requires the Gaussian process model output ranging between 0 and 1, is there any technique to constrain the Gaussian process model's output?

Comment: Do you need it during estimation or only during inference-time? Depending on why you need that, you can find techniques under the name Generalized Gaussian Processes (GGPs)

Comment: My Gaussian process model is developed to estimate an output y given any input set (x1,x2,x3). It has known that all training samples' y are between 0 and 1, and thus I hope estimations from the developed GP models can be between 0 and 1 to approach reality. Can I realize this by you mentioned techniques?

Comment: If you assume $y$ is, for example, Beta-distributed, you should be able to devise a Beta Gaussian Process for that. For example, [Jensen, Bjørn Sand, Jens Brehm Nielsen, and Jan Larsen. "Bounded gaussian process regression." 2013 IEEE International Workshop on Machine Learning for Signal Processing (MLSP). IEEE, 2013.](https://www2.imm.dtu.dk/pubdb/edoc/imm6637.pdf)

Comment: Many thanks, I've solved the problem according to your recommended articles.

Answer (score 3):

The simplest thing to do in such a case is to model a transformed version of $y$ by a Gaussian process. This is not specific to Gaussian processes; transformation is a standard instrument in the statistical toolbox.

Although many appropriate transformations exist, a good default is the logit transform. In stead of modelling
$$y(\cdot) \sim GP(m(\cdot), c(\cdot, \cdot))$$
Let $w = \text{logit}\,(y) = \log(y) - \log(1 - y)$.  You should then model
$$w(\cdot) \sim GP(m(\cdot), c(\cdot, \cdot))$$
and use the inverse-logit $y = \text{logit}^{-1}\,(w)  = \frac{1}{1 + \exp(-w)}$ to obtain predictions for $y$.

Comment: This fails, or needs a work-around, if $y$ is exactly $0$ or exactly $1$, The question isn't explicit on whether "between"  is inclusive or exclusive of these limits.

Answer (score 1):

If you make an assumption that $y$ follows a bounded distribution, it should be possible to devise an appropriate Gaussian Process that respects that assumption.

If, for example, $y$ is Beta-distributed, see:

- [Jensen, Bjørn Sand, Jens Brehm Nielsen, and Jan Larsen. "Bounded gaussian process regression." 2013 IEEE International Workshop on Machine Learning for Signal Processing (MLSP). IEEE, 2013.](https://www2.imm.dtu.dk/pubdb/edoc/imm6637.pdf)